# gold linker on ubuntu 11.04 does not search /usr/local/lib by default

Tags: c++, linker, ubuntu-11.04

I am trying to use the gold linker to compile my code, but it does not search for libraries in /usr/local/lib by default. I tried adding /usr/local/lib in /etc/ld.so.conf.d/ and it still does not work. It is as if gold is not checking the /etc/ld.so.conf stuff. I can add

```
-L/usr/local/lib
```

in my Makefile and it works, but is there an other way to make gold search it by default?

Thanks

UPDATE:

I found the creator of gold talking about the issue http://old.nabble.com/gold-library-search-path--td32057398.html. It seems gold just does not support it as of July 2011.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are also the LDFLAGS   enviroment variable, but like ld.so.conf it might be LD specific with gold not respecting them.

In that case, only going through the gold documentation will help.

Comment: Gold does not seems to check LDFLAGS.